# Angular Universal and jQuery causes page not to be rendered correctly

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-universal

Angular Universal seems to have a problem with jQuery. Calling a simple jQuery function inside an angular component causes that the entire page is not rendered completely:

```
// home.component.ts
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

declare var jquery: any;
declare var $: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    @Language() lang: string;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        $('.tp-banner').show(); // just for the sake of demonstration...
    }
}


// home.component.html
<div class="tp-banner-container">
    <div class="tp-banner">
        This is my home
    </div>
</div>

// front.component.html
<app-header-menu></app-header-menu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

// header-menu.component.html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <ul id="top_links">
        <li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems">
            <span (click)="selectLocale(menuItem.language)">
                {{ menuItem.text}}
            </span>
        </li>
        <li id="social_top">
            <a href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So as you can see, the `HomeComponent` is loaded in the `router-outlet` included in the `FrontComponent`. But it seems that as soon as the HomeComponent includes some jQuery script, the entire app isn't rendered anymore completely (for example the `ngFor` used in the header menu).

Source code **NOT** completely rendered:

```
<app-header-menu _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c1="">
    <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <ul _ngcontent-c1="" id="top_links">
            <!---->
            <li _ngcontent-c1="" id="social_top">
                <a _ngcontent-c1="" href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank"><i _ngcontent-c1="" class="icon-facebook"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</app-header-menu>
```

As soon as I remove the jQuery part, everything works fine

```
<app-header-menu _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c1="">
    <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <ul _ngcontent-c1="" id="top_links">
            <!---->
            <li _ngcontent-c1="">
               <span _ngcontent-c1="">
                   english
               </span>
            </li>
            <li _ngcontent-c1="">
               <span _ngcontent-c1="">
                   deutsch
               </span>
            </li>
            <li _ngcontent-c1="" id="social_top">
               <a _ngcontent-c1="" href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank"><i _ngcontent-c1="" class="icon-facebook"></i></a>
            </li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</app-header-menu>
```

Comment: On server side there is no browser, so you shouldn't be touching native DOM directly when you're using server-side rendering, alway use [`Renderer2`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) API to perfrom DOM manipulation, also that will happen to work on server side as well.

Comment: @PankajParkar, so in other words, forget about jquery for SSR?

Comment: I think it could be possible with the help of `jsdom`, but it will be bit tedious. Even the recommend way is to use Renderer2 api.. *Not completely sure about what I stated*

Comment: You should check everywhere in your code where you use jQuery wether the code is executing server-side or client-side